# International resources

Tags: java, struts2

In my international  resources, the code is

:

```
post_badge_format = You've earned the "{0}" badge for {1}.
```

In my java

code:

```
String messageContent = MessageFormat.format(messageType, paramValues);
```

The expected value of messageContent should like this:

```
You've earned the "XXX" badge for XXX.
```

But the actual value of messageContent is like this:

```
You've earned the "{0}" badge for {1}.
```

Why?

Comment: did you try to debug it? Are the `paramValues` correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the international resources, the code should like this:

```
post_badge_format = You've earned the "'{0}'" badge for '{1}'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using ActionSupport:

[public String getText(String aTextName,
                      List args)](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html#getText%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.List%29)

In your action assuming it extends from ActionSupport replace it with this:

```
String messageContent = getText(messageType, paramValues);
```